# Hive str_to_map

Tags: hive, hiveql, udf

I have a sample data as below
Id(string),   delimProperties(string)
==   ==============

1, foo.prop=foo value|bar.prop=bar value
2, foo2.prop=foo2 value|bar2.prop=bar2 value

Here is my dml
1)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_data(Id STRING, delimProperties STRING)<br>
row format delimited <br>
fields terminated by ","<br>
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|' <br>
map keys terminated by '='<br>
STORED AS textfile;<br>
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS final_data(Id STRING, delimProperties STRING)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ","
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
map keys terminated by '=';
```

3)

```
alter table final_data add columns (properties map<string,string>);
```

4)

```
load data local inpath 'file:/c:/data/sample.csv' into table test_data;
```

5)

```
insert into table final_data select Id,
str_to_map(delimproperties,'|','=')
from test_data;
```

6)

```
Select * from final_data limit 1;
```

1                     {"":"", " ":null, ".":null}

Any idea what I must be doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone has any ideas as to why this should not work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `'|'` character as it has special meaning in Java regular expression, which is used by `string.split(..)` here

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFStringToMap.java.

This should work:

```
insert into table final_data select Id,
str_to_map(delimproperties,'\\|','=')
from test_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
str_to_map(delimproperties,'[|]','=')
```

Comment: Some explanation about why this works would be helpful